# Using MATLAB to define a function in signal processing 101

Tags: matlab

I want to define a function $y(t)$ that has 2 cases:

$$y(t)=
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{for} & -T \lt t \leq 0 \\
1 & \text{for} & 0 \lt t\leq T
\end{cases}
$$
where $T$ is an integer.

I already defined $t$ using linspace between $-T$ to $T$ in a resolution of 1000 points.

I was advised to use the command `ones`, but I dont know how to apply it by the function terms.

Thank you.

Comment: `y=[-ones(500,1);ones(500,1)];`

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
I just dont understand how does it work, because when I plotted (t,y) it gave me exactly what I wanted, but ones(500,1) gives you a vector of 500 1's, and it has nothing to do with t.
 Im just trying to understand this better.

Comment: You're right, `y` has nothing to do with `t`, just the lengths of the two vectors must be the same. `y` simply gives you the values, and `t` defines *where* on the t-axis these values are located. That's the way it works.

Comment: Why not to use the `sign` function and set the value for `t=0` to be 1?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is Octave but should work in Matlab:

```
function y=Y(t)
  y=ones(size(t));
  y=y+(t<=0)*(-2);
```

.. and it is vectorised. Calling will look like:

```
>t=linspace(-T,T,1000);
>y=Y(t);
```

To make this more general we could also make the time at which the function switches a parameter also:

```
function y=Y(t,S)
  y=ones(size(t));
  y=y+(t<=S)*(-2);
```